# How to retrieve the entire folder contents in Filenet 5.2?

Tags: java, filenet, filenet-content-engine

There are methods like
`get_Subfolders()` and `get_ContainedDocuments()` available through the `Folder` interface in `Filenet`'s `Java API`.

I've already tried using `get_Containees()`, but it returns an empty list (iterator has no next entry).

Is there any way to retrieve both, folders and documents without making two network calls? Are there any tricks to do that?

Comment: always good to mention the version of FileNet that you are using

Comment: Im using 5.2.1 :)  sorry

Answer (score 0):

`Folder.get_Containees` retrieves referentially contained objects (folders, documents, custom objects) in the folder.

```
Folder.get_ContainedDocuments method to retrieve all documents contained in the folder.
```

ex:

```
String folderPath = "/DocFolder/MyDocs";
Folder myFolder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(os, folderPath, null);
DocumentSet myLoanDocs = myFolder.get_ContainedDocuments();
```

Comment: Folder.get_Containees() - ok. But how do you iterate over it? How do you retrieve a Folder/Document from it?

Comment: it gives you ReferentialContainmentRelationshipSet which has iterator or pageiterator and you can iterate it